# Providing a packaging NPM command in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have finished an assignment for a software engineering role, and I'm having trouble with the last requirement.
I need to provide a packaging NPM command "npm build" that builds and publishes the front end I have developed in angular to the backend project.
I guessed I just need to include the script : "npm build" in the scripts area in my package.json file, but I was wrong.

Here is my package.json file in the frontend:

```
{
  "name": "item-managment-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "npm build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

How can I build and publish my frontend project to a folder in my backend project, suppose it was located in : /Desktop/project ?
Thanks.

EDIT: this is the angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "item-managment-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/item-managment-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "item-managment-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "item-managment-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "item-managment-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "item-managment-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "item-managment-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "item-managment-app"
}
```

Comment: Add your angular.json file

Comment: @HitechHitesh added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in angular.json file

```
"options": {
            "outputPath": "/Desktop/project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfils": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

Change the output path in the options of angular.json file as shown above.

The above will create in the folder of the provided path location.  Be careful because it has / in it.  The. Last folder name that is `project` will be deleted completely and rhen created again then the build be put in.  So be careful the providing the path

Other paths deploy syntax to try

`"outputPath": "../../../Desktop/project",`

`"outputPath": "E://Desktop/project",`

The npm command to build angular for production is

`ng build --prod`

So in package.json file change the line

`"build":"ng build --prod",`

Then run `npm run build`

Comment: That's great, thanks, but how do I add that "npm build" command to really build the angular project to the destination folder?

Comment: Added in answer

Comment: Removed extra inverted coma

Comment: Thanks, works great! any idea how to remove the extra "run" in the command "npm run build"

Comment: Is there any way to remove the "run" from the command?